# Do we know where the Matthew 2:6 prophecy is from?

Tags: matthew, prophecy, messiah

Do we have a document recording that this was prophesied? Is it in the Old Testament somewhere?

Matthew 2, KJV

> 4 And when he [Herod] had gathered all the chief priests and scribes of the people together, he demanded of them where Christ should be born.

> 5 And they said unto him, In Bethlehem of Judaea: for thus it is written by the prophet,

> 6 And thou Bethlehem, in the land of Juda, art not the least among the princes of Juda: for out of thee shall come a Governor, that shall rule my people Israel.

Comment: Have you read Micah 5:2 (English bibles) / Micah 5:1 (Hebrew Tanakh)?

Comment: No.  Thats the answer thank you. Feel free to write that, or I can in a minute. Surprised that some Bibles dont reference it

Comment: I also learned if my bible doesnt have such in a reference to check online versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthew 2:

> 6
> But you, **Bethlehem**, in the land of Judah, are by no means least among the rulers of Judah, for out of you will come a ruler who will be the shepherd of My people Israel.

It was popularly known by the Jews that the Messiah would come from Bethlehem, John 7:

> 42
> Hath not the scripture said, That Christ cometh of the seed of David, and out of the town of **Bethlehem**, where David was?

Do we know where the Matthew 2:6 prophecy is from?

Yes, from Micah who prophesied in 5:

> 2 But you, **Bethlehem** Ephrathah, who are small among the clans of Judah, out of you will come forth for Me One to be ruler over Israel--One whose origins are of old, from the **days of eternity**.

"Days of eternity" shows the eternal existence of Jesus the Messiah.

Comment: Your final sentence  is a stretch